# Xamly begin a storyboard when a RoutedCommand is called?

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, routed-commands, icommand

Is there a way to begin a storyboard wen an ICommand is executed **WITH XAML**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoutedCommands involve some code-behind, but this is definitely doable.

The simplest way is to add a CommandBinding to the parent control. Something like this:

```
    <UserControl>
      <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Exit" Executed="HandleExit"/>
     </UserControl.CommandBindings>
   </UserControl>
```

Then in your code-behind event handler named 'HandleExit', invoke the storyboard either by name or from the Resources collection.

Let me know if you need some more clarification.

Comment: You will also have to define an equivalent RoutedCommand or use one of the built-in RoutedCommands (ApplicationCommands, MediaCommands, etc). This solution won't work for a simple ICommand, unfortunately.

Comment: I thought about doing it xamly, with no code involved, better said, beggining the Storyboard with Xaml when the command is hit, but I guess it's impossible.